# LINQ - How to merge two lists and sum specific field when the ids are matched

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge

Considering I have 2 lists (`firstList` and `secondList`), both are with the same properties, but with different values.

I need the result for merging both lists, but it must consider the case the field `IdALuno` match the Id of the `secondList` and it should sum the values of property `Nota`.

I`ve seen a couple of examples here nothing that could work in this specific case.

This is my expected result:

- The `idAluno` of all lists must appear in the `finallist`
- When `idAluno` matches both lists, it should sum the field `Nota`

| IdALuno | Nota |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        class Semestre
        {
            public int Nota { get; set; }
            public int IdALuno { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            List<Semestre> firstList = new List<Semestre>();
            firstList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 1, Nota = 5 });
            firstList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 2, Nota = 4 });
            firstList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 3, Nota = 3 });
            firstList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 5, Nota = 3 });

            List<Semestre> secondList = new List<Semestre>();
            secondList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 1, Nota = 4 });
            secondList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 3, Nota = 5 });
            secondList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 4, Nota = 2 });
            secondList.Add(new Semestre { IdALuno = 6, Nota = 3 });   


            foreach (var item in firstList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"idALuno: {item.IdALuno} / Nota: {item.Nota}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Linq` to:

1. Group by `IdALuno` and sum all `Nota`.
2. Order by `IdALuno`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<Semestre> result = new List<Semestre>();

result.AddRange(semestre1);
result.AddRange(semestre2);

result = result.GroupBy(x => x.IdALuno)
    .Select(x => new Semestre
            {
                IdALuno = x.Key,
                Nota = x.Sum(y => y.Nota)
            })
    .OrderBy(x => x.IdALuno)
    .ToList();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3piElQ)

Comment: Thank you Yong, thats exactly i was expecting

Comment: Yong, I have another one, a little more complex, because it has sublist on in. I have tried to use this example to aply in this other case.  If you could help me out in this another one, I would be really grateful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142242/how-to-merge-two-lists-using-linq-suming-especifics-fields-with-sublists?noredirect=1#comment127467600_72142242